# Android : Bold Tag not working in textview after applying fontfamily

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some text with html tag  and I wanted to show this text in my Textview with bold. But as I am applying fontFamily, I couldn't able to view the bold effect. If I remove fontFamily then only I can able to see the bold effect.

**Any suggestions how it can be done ?**

NB. the text will be coming from server in actual scenario, just to explain I have written it hardcoded

**inside Fragment**

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("setText")
    fun setText(view: EmojiAppCompatTextView) {
            val text = "Hi <b> this must be bold </b> ok"
            view.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }
}
```

---

**XML**

```
 <androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_point"
                style="@style/Body1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:setText="@{viewHolder}" />
```

---

**Style**

```
<style name="Body1">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_14ssp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/source_sans_pro</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    </style>
```

---

**FONT**

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Source Sans Pro"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```